# Startup user script for sh (on alpine)

Tags: linux, sh, alpine-linux

I am trying to figure out how to change the colors of directories for my Alpine based container.

Right now when I run `ls` all the directories are black on blue like this:

[image: black on blue]

It is very hard to read (and hurting my eyes).

I have [read](https://askubuntu.com/questions/466198/how-do-i-change-the-color-for-directories-with-ls-in-the-console) that for BASH you can edit ~/.BASHRC to change the color.

But alpine uses SH not BASH.  When I try to search to find the equivalent file, I just keep getting results for BASH.

I tried looking in the `~/` folder, but the files in there do not seem to be the one I am looking for.

**What is the name and location of the user startup file for SH?**  (Bonus points for info on how to change the directory color in there.)

Comment: Seems to be `~/.profile` (the most common - from here)[https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/3060/290319]

Comment: You can run `man ls` and see if you have `--color` option available. Try `ls --color=none`. This is similar to setting the `LS_COLORS` environment variable in your Bourne Shell's (`sh`) `~/.profile` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The colors you are looking for are chosen by `ls`, not the shell. However, `ls` typically determines the colors to use by looking at the value of a particular environment variable. Check the documentation for your version of `ls`, and edit `~/.profile` (creating it, if necessary) to set the appropriate variable with as instructed.